# Save HTML form and values offline for later processing

Tags: html, forms, save

I have an offline HTML form (see example below) which will have several tick options. The user gets the form sent by email, which he has then to fill offline and send the filled form back for later processing. How could this be implemented? I mean saving the html file when filled does not store the value. Any suggestions, ideas?

```
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="check1" value="ns">
    <label for="check1">Is A correct?</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="check2" value="ns">
    <label for="check2">Is B correct?</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit">Subscribe</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Best
Muleque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use local storage to store the data from the HTML form.
Here is the full implementation example for that.

[Html Local Storage Implementation](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/save-for-later-feature-in-forms-using-localstorage)